# Fetching preset username and password from session doesn't validate

Tags: php, session

I have a new website, and after the administrators logs in, they have to change the username and password from their default values. The password validates, but the username does not.

Please check my for-each loop:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnLogin'])) {
    $adminfirstlogin = array('admin', 'admin');
    $_SESSION['Login'] = $adminfirstlogin;
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $_POST['Username'];
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $_POST['Password'];
    $_SESSION['Work'] = $_POST['Work'];

    $pass = 0; //boolean that will turn yes if username+password matches
    $use = 0;
    $name = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];

    if (empty($name)) {
        echo 'Please enter your username';
    } elseif (empty($password)) {
        echo 'Please enter your password';
    }
    foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) //login
    {
        foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) //admin=>admin
        {
            if ($subkey == $name) {

                if ($subvalue == $password) {

                    header('location:Admin.php');
                } else {
                    die('<p class="DBsuccess">The password you typed is incorrect</p>');
                }

            } else {
                die('<p class="DBsuccess">Your username is wrong</p>');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` in your working code? And if your form element is `name="username"`, then that won't wash. `username` is not the same as `Username`. Those are possible scenarios. (POST variables are case-sensitive).

Comment: yes it is. session_start() works well, passes my data very well onto my other pages..

Comment: I tend to think that you're overwriting your `username` with `$_SESSION['Username'] = $_POST['Username'];` then you're using `$name = $_POST['Username'];` --- do a `var_dump($_SESSION);` see what you get.

Comment: I have no way to test your code because of probable missing DB info. I can post an answer below to show you what was "successful" for me. Other than that, I can't help you any further. If you're interested to see my answer, let me know. This will give you a start at debugging your present code.

Comment: I am always new to learning Fred :)

Comment: With your present code, I am getting the opposite `Your username is wrong` and not the "password" as you stated *"but the username does not"*. I setup a form of my own for my test. This, when I entered "admin" and "admin" for both fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed my code here:

```
  $adminfirstlogin = array('Armin'=>'admin');
```

It works perfectly now..

Answer (score 0):

The following (*successfully*) produced:

fred
12345

Upon entering `fred` and `12345` in the username and password fields.

I don't know how you're checking for comparisons with the present conditional statements, yet from what I gather, this tells me you're probably checking against a DB.

Base yourself on the following to debug your code. (More code follows below)

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['btnLogin'])) {

    $_SESSION['Username'] = $_POST['Username'];
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $_POST['Password'];

    $name = $_SESSION['Username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['Password'];

echo $name;
echo $password;
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
Username: 
<input type="text" name="Username">
<br>
Password: 
<input type="password" name="Password">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So, there must be something missing or there's a typo somewhere.

With your present code, I am getting the opposite `Your username is wrong` and not the "password" as you stated *"but the username does not"*.

I setup a form of my own for my test. This, when I entered "admin" and "admin" for both fields, maybe your form has a typo or your form element is not named.

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['btnLogin'])) {
    $adminfirstlogin = array('admin', 'admin');
    $_SESSION['Login'] = $adminfirstlogin;
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $_POST['Username'];
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $_POST['Password'];
    $_SESSION['Work'] = $_POST['Work'];

    $pass = 0; //boolean that will turn yes if username+password matches
    $use = 0;
    $name = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];

    if (empty($name)) {
        echo 'Please enter your username';
    } elseif (empty($password)) {
        echo 'Please enter your password';
    }
    foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) //login
    {
        foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) //admin=>admin
        {
            if ($subkey == $name) {

                if ($subvalue == $password) {

                 //   header('location:Admin.php');

echo "ADMIN section";

echo "<br>";
echo $_SESSION['Username']; // this echo'ed successfully
echo "<br>";
echo $_SESSION['Password']; // this echo'ed successfully

                } else {
                    die('<p class="DBsuccess">The password you typed is incorrect</p>');
                }

            } else {
                die('<p class="DBsuccess">Your username is wrong</p>');
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">

Username: 
<input type="text" name="Username">
<br>
Password: 
<input type="password" name="Password">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Submit">
</form>
```